# Simple Qt Application won't compile on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, build, qt4, qt-creator

I've downloaded the Qt SDK and am trying to get started on my first Qt application using Qt Creator.

Using the wizard from the opening splash screen I selected "Qt4 Gui Application" and it threw together a little project for me.

When I try to build that project (without making any changes) I get build errors:

```
Running build steps for project BlockGame...

Configuration unchanged, skipping QMake step.

Starting: /usr/bin/make -w 

make: Entering directory `/Users/mikemorton/BlockGame'

g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -o BlockGame.app/Contents/MacOS/BlockGame main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o -F/Library/Frameworks -L/Library/Frameworks -framework QtGui -framework Carbon -framework AppKit -framework QtCore -lz -lm -framework ApplicationServices

/usr/bin/ld: /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui load command 6 unknown cmd field

/usr/bin/ld: /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore load command 5 unknown cmd field

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [BlockGame.app/Contents/MacOS/BlockGame] Error 1

make: Leaving directory `/Users/mikemorton/BlockGame'

Exited with code 2.

Error while building project BlockGame

When executing build step 'Make'
```

I have no idea why it would give this error when I haven't changed anything in the default project.  I'm not trying to build from the command line, just using Qt Creator.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by reinstalling the developer tools.  I guess something had messed up my version of ld.